# HQL inner join - please explain in simple terms

Tags: hql

In a HQL tutorial, it gives the following example:

```
select s.name, p.name, p.price
from Product p inner join p.supplier as s
```

Product is clearly one of the entities and it looks like it is being joined on it's supplier property, but to what entity is it being joined and what property of that entity is it being joined to.

Please somebody explain it to me.

I understand SQL, and maybe I need a paradigm shift, so please shift me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now your query is incomplete as you have not specified the entity on which you are going to join the two tables.

The two tables can be joined something like this:

```
select s.name, p.name, p.price
from Product p inner join p.supplier as s
on p.id = s.id  --This specifies the entity which you are using to join the table
```

So it means that your table product and supplier are joined by the id column present in the table(*id can be replaced by some other name as present in your table*)

**OR**

If your table has one to many relationship defined then also it is possible. Note that there are two types of JOINS supported by HQL ie., Implicit and Explicit.

EDIT: (adding my comment here so I can tick as the answer I was looking for)

So it seems to me that "underneath" there is already a join in place and that the supplier property has all that information already and that the join syntax is just saying that you wish to use this particular (already set up) join. So the actual entity that it is being joined to and the properties it is joining on is black-boxed away. All I need to know is what properties are on the unknown table (name in the example).

Comment: Maybe that's why the tutorial makes no sense to me - incomplete examples

Comment: So is this tutorial example an implicit join?  If so, what is the join syntax saying?

Comment: @Graham:- I am not sure which tutorial you are using. But it may be the case that there might be a implicit JOIN which the tutorial is referencing. You can refer this tutorial:- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms

Comment: @Graham:- Yes, it looks like that may be that the tables are joined.

Comment: Rahul - the example has the word "join" in it - and the tutorial you link too says it isn't used in implicet joins.  I'll read the whole tutorial and see if it gets any clearer to me

Comment: So it seems to me that "underneath" there is already a join in place and that the supplier property has all that information already and that the join syntax is just saying that you wish to use this particular (already set up) join.  So the actual entity that it is being joined to and the properties it is joining on is black-boxed away.  All I need to know is what properties are on the unknown table (name in the example).  Please correct me if I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @Graham:- No you are perfectly running on the correct path :) All the best!